# Google Photos API - How to filter albums to get photos (JPEG) only while having albumId set?

Tags: google-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm trying to filter contents of an album (to get photos only) coming form Google Photos API, but the docs say that:

> Filters shouldn't be used in a mediaItems:search request if the
>   albumId is set. If a filter is used when the albumId is set, an
>   INVALID_ARGUMENT error (400) is returned.

Does this mean that I have to download all files, than filter the response my self using the MIME type? Or can it still be done directly in the request?

Thanks!

My code:

```
var params = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oauth2-params'));
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST',
          'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search?' +
          'access_token=' + params['access_token'] +
          '&pageSize=25' +
          '&albumId=' + albumId +
          '&pageToken=' + this.albums[albumId].photos.nextPagination);
      xhr.responseType = "json";
      xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

            // handling the respons...


          } else if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(xhr.status, xhr.response);
          }
        };

        xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't specify both a media type and album as a parameter for a search request at the moment. There's a request for this on the issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/116541300). You can 'star' the issue to be notified of any updates.

For now, you can do the filtering on your side, without needing to download the files themselves: Check the `mimeType` and the `mediaMetadata` properties of a [media item](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems#resource-mediaitem). The `mimeType` field indicates what kind of file it is (for example, `image/jpeg` or `image/png`). Alternatively, you can also check whether the [`mediaMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems#mediametadata) property contains a [`photo`](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems#photo).